# Git workflow isn't loading the latest changes

Tags: git, git-workflow

I'm struggeling with a github action on a self-hosted server. I hope someone is able to help.

The installed runner is working fine and is able to be activated on a push to the `deploy` branch. On a push the Action Tab within Github gets a new Job.

Here's the workflow file I'm using:

```
name: react

on: 
  push: 
    branches: [ "deploy" ]
    
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: self-hosted

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [16.x]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        cache: 'npm'

    - run: cd /var/www/subsdrain/code/subsdrain
    
    - run: npm i
    - run: npm run build
    - run: rm -rf /var/www/subsdrain/www/*
    - run: cp -r /var/www/subsdrain/code/subsdrain/build/* /var/www/subsdrain/www
```

I was thinking it might be caused because I'm missing `git fetch` or `git pull origin deploy` for that matter. Both aren't working as well. Any ideas why I'm unable to get the code I see from my deploy branch on github?

according to github actions everything works as intended.

When running the commands manually in the cli the data get's fetched.